# Fixed Margin in Fluid Layout

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="col-1">column 1</div>
  <div id="col-2">column 2</div>
  <div id="col-3">column 3</div>
</div>
```

And I have the following CSS:

```
#wrap {
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  width: 90%;
}

#col-1, #col-2, #col-3 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}
```

At the moment the margin between the "wrap" and the page is fluid.

And there is no spacing between each column ...

How can I make the margin between the wrap and the page fixed to 40px?

And a margin between each column also fixed to 15px?

NOTE: 
I am applying "box-sizing: border-box;" to all elements.
I think it makes easier to solve my problem ...
But I am not sure the best way to do it.

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking... are you talking about this or something more complex than just setting fixed-pixel widths for the margins?

**CSS UPDATED BASED ON MORE INFO IN COMMENT (AGAIN)**

```
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 40px;
}

#wrap {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#col-1, #col-2, #col-3 {
  background: #ccc;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 33.333333%;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

#col-1 { padding: 0 8px 0 0; }

#col-2 { padding: 0 8px; }

#col-3 {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 0 8px;
}

span { background: red; display: block; } /** Just to show content-area **/
```

Codepen sketch: http://cdpn.io/xEueC

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for ... I want the wrap to be centered. On your example I see a right margin bigger then left margin on resizing.

Comment: I see now why this is challenging :)  Here is an updated sketch, which maintains liquidity, but your fixed pixel margins (with numbers that can't be divided as integers) are going to cause issues with the box-model concept. So basically, we should use an even number padding to create your 'margins' while allowing your columns to maintain their 33% liquidity.

Answer (score 0):

With the following markup:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="col-1">column 1</div>
  <div id="col-2">column 2</div>
  <div id="col-3">column 3</div>
</div>
```

I created two examples. Both with column margin fixed to 20px.

In the first example the wrap is centered with 80% page width:
http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/xghzn

For this example the CSS is the following:

```
body {
  background: white;
}

.wrap {
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
}
.col {
  background: blue;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  float: left;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;   
}

.col:first-of-type {padding-left: 0;}

.col:last-of-type {padding-right: 0;}

/* Used to show the usable column area */
.col div {background: yellow;}
```

On the second example the wrap has page width with a 40px left and right margins:
http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/pKgos

On this example I change the wrap CSS to:

.wrap {
  background: red;
  margin: 0 40px;
}

What do you think about this approach?

Any suggestion to improve this is welcome.

Thank You,
Miguel